# Two wordpress mu installs, same settings/plugins/themes?

Tags: multisite

I run two wordpress mu installs. They are both indentical in terms of plugins, themes and network-wide settings. The reason I run two is because they have different root-domains and different superadmins. Is it possible to simplify this setup somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To a certain extent, yes.

Take a look at the [WP Multi Network](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-multi-network/) plugin.  It allows you to have multiple, separate MU networks running off the same installation - same core, same plugins, same themes, same database.

Answer (score 1):

Ron and @andrea-r are heavily involved in the WP multisite community.

They have a decent guide and an up-dated plugin with ebook at http://wpebooks.com/networks/

the plugin addresses the concept of a network of networks

hope that helps?
Damien